# Kubernetes: Get podcount by namespace

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, azure-aks

Im looking to get the number of pods on a cluster by namespace. Is this possible with a kubectl command?

Looking to exclude certain namespaces as well

kubectl get pods gets me a list of every pod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below command:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o json | jq '.items | group_by(.metadata.namespace) | map({"namespace": .[0].metadata.namespace, "NoOfPods": (length)})'
```

Output format:

```
[
  {
    "namespace": "keda",
    "NoOfPods": 3
  },

  {
    "namespace": "kube-system",
    "NoOfPods": 12
  },

  {
    "namespace": "prod",
    "NoOfPods": 1
  },

  {
    "namespace": "stage",
    "NoOfPods": 1
  }

]
```

Comment: This is very helpful. I used a for loop earlier to iterate over all namespaces but this produces results much faster.

Answer (score 1):

I have just modified the command posted in the above answer owing to OP's need of excluding certain namespaces as well.

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o json | jq '[.items[] | select(.metadata.namespace != "logging")] | group_by(.metadata.namespace) | map({"namespace": .[0].metadata.namespace, "NoOfPods": (length)})'
```

Result without exclusion:

[image]

Result after exclusion:

[image]

In here, I'm excluding the pods from `logging` namespace only but you can exclude more namespaces using the format:

```
.metadata.namespace != "logging" and .metadata.namespace != "monitoring"
```

Hope this helps!